# Create custom button in Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

Is there any possible way that I can create my own custom button?

Something like creating a button in Photoshop with a specific extension and then using it inside Qlikview in a correct way, or a button object just  like the others Qlikview already have..

Ps. I know I can use an image in a text object and then set it like a button, but as a image, the file gets heavier...

Can I create a Qlikview button?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends what exactly you need to achieve. You can also look to Qlikview extensions and use something via Css for webmode. Generally I do such a things only in QlikSense as doing it in Qlikview is a bit waste of time as it is hard to achieve good results ;-) like you said in Qlikview just use ready options or just add image.